# how to build rabbitmq C client lib on windows

Tags: rabbitmq

Can somebody throw some light on how to build rabbitmq C client lib on windows?

Answer (score 4):

I've created a [CMake](http://cmake.org/)-ified version of rabbitmq-c of the build system that works cleanly under Windows (VS-2010 tested), and *nix systems:

https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-c/

Edit: wrong link, here is a discussion on the topic: http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2010-February/006201.html

Answer (score 0):

The current [tip](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-c/rev/22cb3bbbca10) for the library for RabbitMQ can be built in windows using mingw. The process is long and a bit complicated but it is documented in the README.windows file [here](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-c/file/22cb3bbbca10/README.windows)